# Extra large gap in article where figure code is, even though figure is at top of page

Tags: spacing, floats, amsart

I writing an article using the `amsart` document class and whenever I use `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` to put a figure into the article, it places the figure at the top of the page (which is fine), but leaves an extra space between the paragraphs.

To be more specific:

```
Paragraph zero text...
Paragraph one text...
begin{figure}...\end{figure}
Paragraph two text...
Paragraph three text...
```

Produces:

```
Figure
Paragraph zero text...
Paragraph one text...

Paragraph two text...
Paragraph three text...
```

When I intend to have the paragraphs follow the same spacing as the others:

```
Figure
Paragraph zero text...
Paragraph one text...
Paragraph two text...
Paragraph three text...
```

Is there a way to adjust the document setting so that that extra space does not appear?

**Edit: Preamble and specific code:**

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=0pt, parskip=0pt, hangindent=0pt, indention=0pt, labelformat=parens, labelfont=rm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\linespread{1.6}
\begin{document}
...vertices arranged in a circle, one of Dante's favorite Euclidean shapes. 

\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=5.5in,height=5.5in]{graphn33} 
\caption{A complete graph with 33 people in heaven, $K_{33}$.}
\label{fig:graphn33} 
\end{figure}
\end{center}

This highly mathematical object displays...
\end{document}
```

If I don't have the spacing between the figure code and the paragraphs, the gap still remains but the paragraphs don't indent properly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of actual code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Please provide further information. I just tested it but cannot confirm that behavior. Perhaps post your preamble and what else might be between the two paragraphs in the source code.

Comment: I imagine the problem you are facing is LaTeX formats your document such that the page is vertically justified, if this makes any sense. I know this happens with the book class but I don't know what could be causing that here, since this is amsart. Perhaps, you could post some of your code? In the absence of any further information, however, I would suggest you specify the placement of the figure by passing an optional argument: "[h]" (here) or "[htbp]". The default is "[tbp]" (top/bottom/parse).

Comment: I edited the original question to include specific code. I tested this sample code and it produced the same effect as the entire document.

Comment: @Jimi: You shouldn't just use `[h]`. It will be replaced by `[ht]` (since it is possible that there is no space for the figure at the specified place).

Comment: @Caramdir: You are certainly right, [h] is essentially [htbp]. I thought that was implicit in my comment, though, but I guess I was also lazy in not mentioning [hbp] or other permutations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is the `center` environment. It adds some vertical space, that is not floated to the top because it is outside the `figure`. You should replace it by `\centering` inside the `figure` (inside because you only want it to apply to the `figure`). `\centering` doesn't add any space.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5.5in,height=5.5in]{graphn33} 
    \caption{A complete graph with 33 people in heaven, $K_{33}$.}
    \label{fig:graphn33} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you. I wish I could upvote you, but I can't until I hit 15 reputation. I'll come back and do so once I hit that.

Comment: @Alec: I did that for you! However, you can and should mark this as the answer to your question so posters know your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `\raggedbottom` in your preamble, for the case that it's caused by a `\flushbottom` or similar setting. During testing, I noticed vertical stretching even with amsart defaults, which have been canceled by `\raggedbottom`.

Comment: Wow, didn't know the ragged-'s also dealt with vertical alignment! That's one that may come in handy for me in the future.